# Assigning string to div value from javascript function across pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web app that outputs the results of a function as a double.  The function compares two text documents and returns the percentage indicating the percentage of similarity between the two documents.  When the user clicks a Compare button, the function runs and takes the user from the compare.jsp page to the results.jsp page, and displays a loading-bar that is filled in like so:

```
<div id="levenshtein-distance"
     class="ldBar label-center levenshtein-distance"
     data-preset="fan"
     data-value="${result.percentage}"
     data-stroke="">
</div>
```

This works fine, the fan bar gets the correct percentage.  However, I am also trying to color the fan bar using the data-stroke value based on this percentage.  I have a simple javascript function to do this, but can't figure out how to pass the value.  I've tried running the function in the body tag of the results.jsp page using "onload", but this doesn't work.  Here is my JavaScript function:

```
function barSetLD(percent) {
  var red = "red";
  var green = "green";
  var orange = "orange";

  var elem = document.getElementById("levenshtein-distance");

  if (percent <= 40.00) {
    elem.setAttribute("data-stroke", green);
  } else if (percent > 40.00 && percent <= 70.00) {
    elem.setAttribute("data-stroke", orange);
  } else {
    elem.setAttribute("data-stroke", red);
  }
}
```

I've done quite a bit of searching and can't seem to find an example that helped me solve this.  Any help is very much appreciated.

////Update:

Trinh, that worked to change the color, thanks!  My problem now is that I do, in fact, have multiple 'levenshtein-distance' ids and I am looping through them.  So currently everything is being set to the same color.  I should have mentioned this initially, sorry.  I am comparing multiple pairs of files and outputting the loading-bar for each pair.  If you have some idea about how to resolve the looping issue, that would be great, but thanks for the original solution either way!  I updated my javascript function as follows:

```
function barSetLD(percent) {
var red = "red";
var green = "green";
var orange = "orange";

var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=levenshtein-distance]");

for (var i in elem) {
    if (percent <= 40.00) {
        elem[i].setAttribute("data-stroke", green);
    } else if (percent > 40.00 && percent <= 70.00) {
        elem[i].setAttribute("data-stroke", orange);
    } else {
        elem[i].setAttribute("data-stroke", red);
    }
}
```

}

And the full bit of code with the html loop is, and I am now calling the barSetLD(percent) at the very bottom of the page as you suggested:

```
<c:forEach items="${studentResults}" var="result" varStatus="loop">
    <div id="levenshtein-distance"
         class="ldBar label-center levenshtein-distance"
         data-preset="fan" 
         data-value="${result.percentage}">
    </div>
</c:forEach>

<script type="text/javascript">
    barSetLD("${result.percentage}");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code at the very bottom of the page where all DOM has been loaded. Or at least make sure `<div id="levenshtein-distance"/>` exist and fully loaded before calling this `document.getElementById("levenshtein-distance");`. Also double check if you have multiple `levenshtein-distance` id...

Comment: Thanks, Trinh!  The color is now changing.  I updated my original question to reflect the results.